# Accessing a single ressource (here tcp socket) from different threads

Tags: c#, locking

It may be a bit of a fundamental question, but I would like to know if my programming is accepted as being good practice :-)

My code consists of a c# communication class, that uses underlying tcp socket object. But it also may be any other object that supports open, close, read and write access.

A single piece of communication consists of a sending a telegram and waiting for the answer from the other side.

Until now I only accessed this c# class from within one thread, and it worked fine. Today I tested it with a couple of parallel working threads, created in and started from a form class and the communication object was an object in the form class. The threads (simply a method of the form class) could access the communication object at any time.

But unfortunately, because of no locking, one thread could receive the answer telegram of another thread.
To solve this, I simply put all my calling functions inside a lock(){} statement:

```
public Boolean Read(UInt16 adress,out UInt16 value)
{
    lock(this)
    {
        // send the read telegram and receive 
        // an ACK Telegram with the data
        value = _connection.Read(adress);
    }
 }

public Boolean Write(UInt16 adress,UInt16 value)
{
    lock(this)
    {
        // send the Write telegram and receive 
        // an ACK Telegram with the data
        return _connection.Write(adress,value);
    }
 }
```

The code in this example doesn't resemble the actual code, but the lock() is the interesting thing.
My questions now are:

- Is the lock mechanism robust enough?
- If many threads are waiting to enter the lock, is it guaranteed that every waiting thread will gain access? And in such matter, that even faster threads don't block slower threads?
- Would it be practical to program some kind of scheduler, that lets the threads access the object one after another?

**[edit as answer to comment #1]**
I cannot give more detailed source code, because it's all to complex to post - multiple objects for protocol details, socket encapsulation and all those things.

- My methods all use synchronous calls to the socket.
- Every method sends a piece of data (the telegram) and waits until it gets the complete answer telegram or the socket times out.

You wrote something about queuing. I never took this into account. But IIRC the original implementation of my library (good old c++ code from pre 2000) took some kind of queuing to address this issue with COM/DCOM communication.

Perhaps I should then take a look at this code once more. 
My other solution to multithreaded communication over my class object would be to use multiple class objects at the same time. Then each thread would use its own socket connection and nothing would be mixed up.

On the other hand, my target server on the other side of communication uses a multithreaded approach to handle each socket connection, and then with some locking mechanism (Mutexes) and synchronisation (Events) it queues the parallel telegrams into the serial queue of the server.

**[edit #2]**
Does a lock(this) in different methods prevent the other thread to call Read() while the first thread is calling Write() ?

Comment: Have you looked into queuing technologies?

Comment: Same as @CamBruce said. You never read/write multithreaded from a socket (or other). How does a thread know when a message arrives for him? And when sending, you don't want to mix-up messages, when sending messages from different threads. Threadsafety can't be completely fixed by putting all within locks. If you provide more about, what and how you're implementing. We might give you an alternative (if needed)

Comment: @Elydasian, thank you for editing my post. It seems like you have a lot of time at hand... This post is 2 years old now, so I never suspected it to be changed again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through different tests with my code, and it seems like there is nothing bad about using

```
lock(this)
{}
```

But its really not good practice to read/write a Socket from multiple threads. 
So I think i will have both locks in place:

- lock(this){}
- Checking Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId against the one used in the constructor.

the first one will prevent the same thread from entering two different methods at the same time (one in the normal program flow and the other when used with invoke-patterns).